# How can I Solve this error when iOS build in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, build

How can I solve this error?

Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.school.wcc2' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.school.wcc2'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

It appears that there was a problem signing your application prior to installation on the device.

Verify that the Bundle Identifier in your project is your signing id in Xcode
open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Also try selecting 'Product > Build' to fix the problem:
Encountered error while building for device.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project folder, open the iOS project in Xcode. On the left hand side, select the root, navigate to signing and capability

It would loo something like this.

[image]

In order to deploy your app in iPhone, you would need development provisioning profile. If you manage your developer account you can go for "Automatically manage signing" and Xcode would do all the needful.

Else, you would need to request the provisioning certificate from your team.

After creating the profile, restart your IDEs.

Comment: Above pic is for reference only, once you fix it you won't have those warning you see in picture.